# Передача значений массива или функции из одного файла в другой React

Tags: reactjs

Задачка попроще, но тем не менее для меня непонятная, ибо везде разные ответы и мне ничего не понятно(

Есть два файла app.js и table.js

В первом файле у меня есть массив в константе

```
   const Products = 
  {
    name: "one",
    id: "1"
  }
```

и функция

```
function travell(Products) {
  return Products.name;
}
```

Во втором файле у меня функция, куда надо передать значения функции из первого файла. Чтобы я не делала пишет, что не видит значений функции.

```
function Tables (Products) {
    return (
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
               
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Полный код 1ого и 2ого файла, кому это будет необходимо

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Tables from './Tables/Tables';

function travell(Products) {
  return Products.name;
}

const Products = 
  {
    name: "one",
    id: "1"
  }


function App() {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Product</h1>
      
      <Tables />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Второй

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.js';
import App from '../App';

function Tables (Products) {
    return (
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
               
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    )
}
export default Tables
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не передаете пропсы в дочерний компонент `Tables`

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Product</h1>
            <Tables Products={Products}/>
        </div>
    );
}

function Tables (props) {
    // >> props.Products
    return (
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    )
}
```